# I keep getting a "[...]/bin/*-ar: not found" error while building the V8 javascript engine for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, v8

I'm trying to build the V8 javascript engine for Android but I can't succeed for some reason. I follow the instructions given [here](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/D8OnAndroid). It all starts very well. I can issue the `make android_arm.release -j8` command from my terminal and it seems very sweet for a while. Then suddenly I get this output:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/dbm/android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/*-ar: not found
```

The statement is correct: there is no `*-ar` file at the specified location.

***But what is an `*-ar` file? And how can I resolve this error?***

The environment is a beast running Ubuntu 12.10 on a 64-bit architecture (with ia32-libs installed) and I build for/with/against Android NDK r8c.

Comment: Same here. Are you using x64?

Comment: Yes. I'm inches away from setting up a 32-bit virtual machine and try it there as well.

Comment: As a workaround you can go ahead and downgrad to use r8b. Sadly bugs are very frequent in Android NDK.

Comment: Hm... why didn't I think of that? Great tip, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a problem in Ubuntu!?
Anyway - extracting via `tar -jxf` worked for me. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41187

Comment: This is really good stuph! Rocked my world and granted a green check-mark :-)

Comment: Seems to have been fixed in 12.10 proposed.

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies with the fact that the NDK build system prefixes the platform name to the commands that are run to build the source. If you notice the error you get, the correct platform prefix is missing from `*-ar`. Somehow, the platform name is being set to `*` instead of the correct prefix `arm-linux-androideabi` (giving the correct name `arm-linux-androideabi-ar`). You'll need to figure out where this information is being skipped. That should fix your problem.

PS. If I get some free time, I'll try and replicate your issue and see if I can give you the exact fix.

Comment: Awesome! I too suspect my environment not being set up properly. But I don't know really why. I'll dig into the build scripts beginning of next week...

Comment: It'll be at least Wednesday before I get time to dig into the root cause. Till then see if you can create a custom Android.mk for the project after running the configure script. That's what I did for a couple of other builds.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'tar -jxf' to extract the android ndk. If you use the 'Extract here' option, it seems to be leaving out some files.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the tip given by the accepted answer and it worked for me too. Thanks for taking the time to answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

`ar` is archive utility from gnu tools. Normally you should have a `$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar` available in your tool chain. which looks like missing in yours.

Comment: Great help! Thanks a lot! Googling for `arm-linux-androideabi-ar` gives me a lot of information of what it is and so, but I still can't get hold of it. I now know what my problem is (thanks to you :-) but I still seem to have problems solving it. Do you have any further tips perhaps? Should I build my custom, stand-alone tool chain?

Comment: I've NDK r8c and it contains arm-linux-androideabi-ar at the specified place. Any chance you get it deleted?

Comment: I've now found the `*-ar` file, but at a different location: `$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ar`. I have created a symlink to the `ar` file (from the original, 'expected', location) - just as an ugly hack and the build process indeed gets somewhat further but I keep getting other linking issues (`collect2: cannot find 'ld'`). It all seems like there is something fundamentally wrong with my setup and paths... Any final thoughts?

Comment: I think it is just your system, may be it was a problem in extracting the ndk installation package. What is inside $NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin ?